# How bindValue with % in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

```
$query = $connect->prepare("SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.id 
FROM users INNER JOIN users_friends ON users.id=users_friends.uID
WHERE bID=:USER AND type =:type AND accepted = '1' AND (users.firstname LIKE '%:queryString%' OR users.lastname LIKE '%:queryString%') 
LIMIT 10");
$query->bindValue(":queryString", $queryString);
$query->bindValue(":type", $type);
$query->bindValue(":USER", $USER);
$query->execute();
```

This is what I have.

Im having error when I try to bindValue and then use it in the prepared statement ( %:queryString% )

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should do

```
"... LIKE :query ..."
```

and then

```
$query->bindValue(":query", $queryString); //where $queryString is '%someQuery%'
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `%` can be a wildcard or a literal %. This code does not make any distinction.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function admin_search($conn,$search_key){

$stmt = $conn->prepare("
SELECT name,criteria,description,pic from brd_det WHERE name LIKE(:n1)
                         UNION

SELECT name,criteria,description,pic from cus_det WHERE name LIKE (:n2)
                             UNION

SELECT name,criteria,description,pic from doc_det WHERE name LIKE (:n3)
                             UNION

SELECT name,criteria,description,pic from par_det WHERE name LIKE (:n4)
                             UNION 

SELECT name,criteria,description,pic from pro_det WHERE name LIKE(:n5)
                             UNION 

SELECT name,criteria,description,pic from ser_det WHERE name LIKE (:n6)
                             "); 

     for ($i=1; $i < 7 ; $i++) { 

        $stmt->bindvalue('n'.$i,'%'.$search_key.'%'); 

     }
     //
    $result=$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer in order to improve it and make it easier for future readers to understand.